# Get only content text from wikipedia api

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mediawiki

Hi i have been scratching my head towards Wikipedia api from past few days and things are not working.

I want to get only content text from a wiki page using Wikipedia REST API. I have looked at other SO Questions and blogs but nothing is working out. I need to get content from random wikipedia page every time user opens their app.

Anyone can direct me towards right direction, i have read API docs also but that also did not help.

Comment: I have not looked at the API (yet) so I'm just thinking out loud... I'm curious if it would be a good idea to use a web crawler (perhaps **JSOUP** because it is quick and simple), to generate the page 'pointer' used by the Wikipedia API. Then randomize whichever page gets crawled to give you the "content" you need when the user opens the app.

Comment: I have to make sure content is of minimum 10 sentences how to do that with JSoup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android Wikipedia api game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854619/android-wikipedia-api-game)