# android Wikipedia api game

Tags: java, android, layout, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

Hi i have to make an app with the following requirement:

```
When the user opens the app, it displays the text from a random Wikipedia page. 
(You’re free to use any logic for grabbing text from a random Wiki 
page(preferably using REST APIs)) The game requires a minimum of 10 lines of 
text on the screen. However, we want to show complete paragraphs of text to 
make it easier to understand the content displayed. Use the least number of 
paragraphs required to cross the 10 sentence limit.
```

I am able to get text from random wiki page but many times text is less than 10 sentences and to ensure minimum 10 sentences i used this url:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&generator=random&exsentences=10

But this url is also not working as expected.

How do i approach this problem any suggestions will help.

Comment: `not working as expected` how do you expect it to work?

Comment: I expect it to get 10 sentences from random page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I notice in your query. First, the `exintro` means you only get sentences from over the first heading. Only a few articles have ten sentences before that. Second, you are getting results from all namespaces. By using `grnnamespace=0` you will only get articles. So something like this might work for you:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&generator=random&exsentences=10&grnnamespace=0

Comment: Thanks but still the same issue many times i get less than 10 sentences for example after running this url i got:  "extract":"<p>The <b>Grim Reaper</b> is a personification of death.</p>"

Comment: I believe it is as expected, that is the last complete sentence in that article.

Comment: Okay so what should i do if i get less than 10 sentences should i refetch until i get 10 sentences but i guess that will delay my UI any suggestions?

Comment: If you must have 10 sentences, in many cases you will have to refetch (because not all articles have 10 sentences).

Comment: Thanks and how should i remove html tags from this text any way out?

Comment: You can add &explaintext=1 to remove the HTML.